# How to convert copy-pasted vertical list of numbers into a python array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of numbers (from a google doc table) and I want to convert them into a python array. I copied and pasted the numbers into my python file and it is formatted like this:

```
nums = 
40.3
55
45.7
43.3
50.3
45.9
53.5
43
44.2
44
47.4
44
33.6
55.1
48.8
50.4
37.8
60.3
46.6
```

Is there any sort of key shortcut or method/function I could use to convert the vertical column of numbers into a python array? The editors I am using are Replit and PyCharm.

Comment: what editor do you use?

Comment: Repl.it. Trying to calculate some statistics quickly. If you know of any that work for PyCharm that would also be appreciated.

Comment: add this to your question for clarification.

Comment: you can copy your nums to a proper editor, format there, e.g. with vim, then paste into repl.it

Comment: Do you have any resources on how to format a column into an array in vim? Or just separate all the numbers with commas?

Comment: You could use Pandas to read clipboard and then convert to numpy array or a list

Comment: You can block select the first column and use `I,<esc>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional way of declaring an array in Python as a literal (rather than as a big pile of `.append()` calls) is like:

```
nums = [40.3, 55, 45.7, ...]
```

or:

```
nums = [
    40.3,
    55,
    45.7,
    ...
]
```

If you can't quickly get from your copy+pasted number list to one of those formats in your editor of choice, you could also do the very cheesy thing of wrapping the copypasta in a multiline string and then converting it at runtime:

```
nums = [float(num) for num in """
40.3
55
45.7
43.3
50.3
45.9
53.5
43
44.2
44
47.4
44
33.6
55.1
48.8
50.4
37.8
60.3
46.6
""".split()]
```

```
>>> nums
[40.3, 55.0, 45.7, 43.3, 50.3, 45.9, 53.5, 43.0, 44.2, 44.0, 47.4, 44.0, 33.6, 55.1, 48.8, 50.4, 37.8, 60.3, 46.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm, you can press the option key twice and then use the cursors. This produces multiple carets which allows you to easily change your list of numbers into a python array.

Answer (score 0):

Not looping solution. If you prefer to use notepad++, there is an option to select entire line all lines in one shot, using shortcut `ctrl+alt and moving cursor`.

Output:

```
nums = [40.3,
55   ,
45.7 ,
43.3 ,
50.3 ,
45.9 ,
53.5 ,
43   ,
44.2 ,
44   ,
47.4 ,
44   ,
33.6 ,
55.1 ,
48.8 ,
50.4 ,
37.8 ,
60.3 ]
```